# ASP.NET Core OpenId Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, openid-connect

im developing a .net core mvc application with authentication against azure active Directory. My Problem is, that i have two different azure avtice directories which are undepentandend to eachother. Based on the user Input (mail or employenumber) i will decide which active Directory should used.

Any idea or reference?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing a [multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-dev-setup-multi-tenant-app) where the [AAD common endpoint is used as the entry point to the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authenticate) rather than a specific AAD login page. You can configure your application to trust more than one AAD instance. It's rather involved, but MS had good documentation on [how to adopt a single tenant app to multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview). I'd also highly recommend [Vittirio's blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/) as a place to learn about AAD auth, and while you're at it, his book titled 'Modern Authentication with Azure Active Directory for Web Applications'

Once you've turned on multitenancy for your application, you'll want to handle AAD validation yourself by checking the tenant id in the incoming SSO request. You do this by overriding SecurityTokenValidated in UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication. [You can refer to this example where the code validates against a database](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs).

There are other considerations [such as admin consent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/tenantadminconsent?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where an AAD admin has to grant access to restricted permissions to your application. [Good explaination here](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Admin-Consent-for-Permissions-in-Azure-Active-Directory.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I know this Approach, but i don't have any rights on the deployed Cloud. I will host the app as WebApp in an AAD xyz for example. This Application should accept users from another AAD abc and user from xyz without any changes in the infrastructure.

Comment: I updated my answer with more information. Application won't require modification other than updating a white list, but target AAD will have to go through admin consent

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good reliable open-source project for that (Identity Server)

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

And also you can check that (openiddict)

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core

Comment: Do you have any examples how i could examine that? IdentityServer seems to be very complex :-)

Comment: Use openiddict-core, they have samples [https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/samples)